# Get quote from API not working on page load Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to get a Random Quote from an API I'm using, however it's not displaying the quote when the page loads, only after pressing a button, the function isnt binded to anything but works properly when i click the button for some reason. I tried to execute the method which loads the quote from an endpoint properly, but does not enter in the if(quote != null) only when i click the button.

`

```
@page "/"

@inject HttpClient Client
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<body>
<h3 class="title">Breaking bad</h3>
<div class="div1" >
    <input type="text" class="accordion-button"  placeholder="Personaje" @bind="nombre" />
    <input type="button" @onclick="GetCharacter" class="button" />

</div>


    @if (aratzfag == false){
        @GetRandomQuote();
        @if(quote != null){
      <p>@quote[0].quote</p>
  }
    }
   

<div class="div2" style="display:@display">
 

@if (character != null)
{

    <div class="card-body">
        <br>
        

       <Character name=@character[0].name/>
        <Character nickname=@character[0].nickname />
             

   

    @for (int i = 0; character[0].occupation.Length > i; i++){

        string a = character[0].occupation[i];
       <span>@a</span>
       <br/>
    }
        <br />
    @if(character[0].name == "Saul Goodman"){
           
                <img src="https://media.tenor.com/pMhSj9NfCXsAAAAd/saul-goodman-better-call-saul.gif" width="250px" height="250px" />
            
            }else if (character[0].name == "Walter White")
            {
               
            <img src="https://c.tenor.com/0VT7jilszwEAAAAC/mr-white-heisenberg.gif" width="250px" height="250px" />
                

        }
      else{

          
                <img src="@character[0].img" width="250px" height="250px" />
            
        }


    </div>
}else if(character == null){
  
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3>El personaje introducido no existe, introduce bien el nombre</h3>
    </div>
    
}
  
</div>


</body>


@code {
    string nombre = "";
    Class1[] character;
    Class2[] quote;
    string display = "none";
    bool aratzfag = false;




    async Task GetCharacter(){
        //  var task = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<Class1>(Endpoints.GetCharacter(nombre));
        // var jsonString = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        //  Class1[] result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class1[]>(task);

        // Rootobject characterData = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<Rootobject>(Endpoints.GetCharacter(nombre));
        // characters = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class1>(Endpoints.GetCharacter(nombre));
        // var a = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Class1[]>>(Endpoints.GetCharacter(nombre));

        character = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<Class1[]>(Endpoints.GetCharacter(nombre));

        if (character.Length == 0){
            character =  null;

        }
        display = "flex";





        //aa = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class1>(characters);
        // var personaje = Endpoints.GetCharacter(nombre);
        // characters = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<Rootobject>(Endpoints.GetCharacter(characters1.Property1[0].name));

    }


    
        async Task GetRandomQuote()
        {
        quote = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<Class2[]>(Endpoints.GetRandomQuote());
        }



}
```

`

```
I also tried

`
```

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
```

```
        quote = await Client.GetFromJsonAsync<Class2[]>(Endpoints.GetRandomQuote());
 

    }
```

`

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
```

but won't enter in the if statement and show the quote, only when i interact the button. I made sure to debug it and gets the quote from the api but won write it on the page.

[Page loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLMjx.jpg)

[After I click the button on the right of the input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTijj.jpg)

Comment: Please clean a bit your question, so it is more readable. Secondly, you want the random quote to be shown when opening the page and not change the quote everytime you rerender something, use `OnInitializedAsync()`. Your first piece of code shows you calling `GetRandomQuote` (which is `async Task`) in the UI part without `await`, this should be called in the `@code` section.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine THANK YOU, i  legit can't thank you enough for helping me solve it. I just had to add await when calling the method GetRandomQuote() from OnInitializedAsync(). I've spent so much time trying to fix this I didn't know what else to try. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the random quote to be shown when opening the page and not change the quote everytime you rerender something, use `OnInitializedAsync()`. Your first piece of code shows you calling `GetRandomQuote` (which is `async Task`) in the UI part without `await`, this should be called with `await` in the `@code` section.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  await GetRandomQuote();
}
```